# Proper way of initializing variable in multiple if statements or nested ifs

Tags: objective-c

I have some scenarios where I alloc init the variable and then initialize it with some data. For e.g.

```
ABCClass *objectAbc = [[ABCClass alloc] init];  //---- Analyser warning
objectAbc = someOtherObjectOfThisKind;

NSArray *array = [NSArray array];              //---- Analyser warning
array = arrayOfArrays[0];
```

In both the cases analyzer giving me warning `value never read`. What is the proper way of initializing the variable. Am i increasing the retain count?

How to initialize variable in case we have multiple ifs lets say,

```
- (void)computeVariable {
    NSString *var = @"";     // ----Analyser Warning
    if ( [someLabel isEqualToString @"A"] ) {
       var = @"A";
    }
    if ( [someLabel isEqualToString @"B"] ) {
      var = @"B";
    }
... remaining code
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Value stored during its initialization is never read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762161/value-stored-during-its-initialization-is-never-read)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first statement declares a variable, and assigns it a new object of type ÀBCClass`. The second statement assigns this variable another object. Thus the object of the first statement is released (ARC) and never used by your program. You should write these two lines as

```
ABCClass *objectAbc = someOtherObjectOfThisKind;
```

and the analyzer message will disappear. Same for variable `array`.

If your are using ARC you can't retain a variable explicitly. If your are using MRC you have one memory leak for `[[ABCClass alloc] init]`, because you send no `release`to this object. On the other hand `[NSArray array]` would give no leak in MRC due to the memory management rules of Objective C.

Addendum to your edit: If `var` is used after the if block you won't get an analyzer warning, because even both conditions are false, the initial value of `var` is used. You will get an analyzer warning, if `var` is only used inside of the if blocks. In this case, you should move the declaration of `var` in each if block, or doesn't initialize it, e. g. `NSString *var;`.

Comment: How to do this if we have multiple IFS or nested ifs.? Please see my edited question. 


Thanks for your previous explanation

Comment: Thanks for your answer.